# python: dump dictionary containin numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, pickle

I want have dictionaries that contain numpy arrays of different sizes and dimensions as values. I want to dump and reload those dictionaries. The natural choice for this is of course pickle.

Pickle performs this nicely. However, the dumped files are not human readable. The question is now: Is there an alternative to using pickle. Since I need some flexibility, I don't really want to do it myself...

The data size is only a couple of MB, so performance is not so much of an issue.

**Edit to clarify:**

I dump into a .txt
The files look like:

```
(dp0
S'ind_SR1_DO'
p1
(dp2
S'**MEASUREMENT NAME**'
p3
(dp4
S'**MEASURED DATA 1**'
p5
cnumpy.core.multiarray
_reconstruct
p6
(cnumpy
ndarray
p7
(I0
tp8
S'b'
p9
tp10
Rp11
(I1
(I3
I13
tp12
cnumpy
dtype
p13
(S'f8'
p14
I0
I1
tp15
Rp16
(I3
S'<'
p17
NNNI-1
I-1
I0
tp18
bI00
S'9.\x855\x05\x9aN>\x89\xeb\xe4\x14x\rO>!\x8bc\xd9\xe5IP>\xf7\xd5\xb7\xc8\x97\xc5P>\xf0\xaeo\xe7\xfc\xb1Q>\xfb\xd3Y4\xfc\xeaS>\x89S\x91\xee\x82\x15X>g\x90(\x88|\xb3\\>J\x88\xe7\xb0;\xa3`>\x91\xebW\x0c\\\xecc>S\xf5\xa9\xc4B\xb1S>>9($\xb8\x0eT>&\xa5\xaa72\x0e]>GKi\xc1^\xa5\x1a>\x12\x06\xd3s\x816\x1b>,h\x9f?9\xef\x1b>%\x8f\xadqT\xc2\x1c>"F\t\t\xbf_\x1e>\xb7u8[<F!>\xfe\x8aR\xa3\xa6\xa8$>T5\xa6\xaa\x00\x9a(>\xea\xf1"\x0c\x00$,>\xdel>\xe6\xe3\x8d2>\x8am\xe7\xb4\xd76!>^\xc9\xe9\xe7\x06Z!>
```

Which is not a human readable but of course can easily be handled by python/pickle

Comment: Maybe not exactly what you are looking for, but how about saving the numpy arrays via `np.save` and creating something like a dictionary constructor? Are you looking for a text file solution readable with a text editor?

Comment: One option is HDF5, read up on [h5py docs](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/). There are freeware readers to open up & view data [not python dependent] and this is a much better option than csv since data types are maintained.

Comment: What do you mean by the files that are dumped not human readable?

Comment: @MaxCollier see edit. I agree that this might be valuable information.

Comment: @jpp I will have a look into it

Comment: savetxt writes a 2d array as text.

Comment: `h5py` organizes the data into groups and datasets.  datasets can only hold numpy arrays.  The groups are like dictionaries, but you can't directly `dump` a dictionary to a `h5py` file.

Comment: What's your code for dumping the numpy arrays? That might be where the error is